# How to add commas in floating point number

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, number-formatting

how to add commas in floating point number.
means if i have number like 3652 than output will be 3,652.00 and 
if the number will be 3652.359618 than 3,652.36 it's work but for 3652 its not return two decimal points like 3,652.00 
i am using now this code to do that :

```
float num = 3652;
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; 
NSString *newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:num]];
```

Comment: and does this code work?

Comment: @Flexicoder no buddy this code is not working as required.

Comment: do you want to specify decimal separator symbol or floating point separator? or just set rounding limit?

Comment: You want a comma in 3,652.00, but not in 3652.36?

Comment: @mackworth i need both means if my value is 3652 than it will return me 3,652.00 and if value is 3652.359618 than return 3,652.36

Comment: I ran your code as is, and it gave me those results. What do you get?

Comment: @mackworth my result for 3652 give me 3,652 and 3,652.36

Comment: @mackworth in 3652 it's not add floating point like 3652.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to round the float number to make it rounded up to 2 decimal digits as shown below :

```
float num = 3652.359618; 
num = ceilf(num * 100) / 100;
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:num]];

NSRange range= [newString rangeOfString:@"."];
if ( !range.length) {
    newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.00",newString];
}

NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

*The following code works but not sure if this is a good way to achieve. I hope I will get comments/feedback on this. Other better answers are still welcome.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for this code after i need two decimal in floating point value in every number means i need 3652 value will return like 3,652.00

Comment: @user2524618:Updated my answer, plz check

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code:

```
NSString *newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(num*100.0)/100.0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` uses device locale for displaying the numbers and separators. In order to enforce your own formatting, try setting the separators on the `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setThousandsSeparator:@","];
```

Comment: You also need to set minimumFractionDigits to 2.

Comment: No, that's not in the code. He just sets maximumFractionDigits.

Answer (score 0):

With that clarification on the goal, just add:

```
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```